Did Descartes really say if you imagine it, it exists?
one commonly encounters crude presentations of Descartes’ arguments as saying that anything you imagine must be true, but now I come across a passage in the sixth meditation that I had forgotten and that seems to say just that.
…attentius consideranti quidnam sit imaginatio, nihil aliud esse apparet quàm quaedam applicatio facultatis cognoscitivae ad corpus ipsi intime praesens, ac proinde existens
i.e.
when I attentively consider what imagination is, I
find that it is simply a certain application of the cognitive faculty   to a body
which is immediately present to it, and which therefore exists
Here he seems indeed to say that if you imagine a body, it exists. The unicorn problem immediately arises.  I’m probably misunderstanding him. Can someone explain?

D is discussing the difference between imagination and (intellectual) conceivability. See example of triangle (we can imagine a "physical"one) vs chiliagon (we conceive it but we cannot imagine it).

It is not that if we imagine it, it exists but that we can imagine only things we have experienced.

Broadly, no… less so if your translation is reliable.
You seem to seek a direct comparison between 400-year-old French and modern English, via Latin.
How reasonable could that be, whether or not scholars had written tomes you should have read?
You seem to confuse cause and effect, interpreting both differently than Descartes did.
As Mauro ALLEGRANZA suggests, Descartes ancient idea of 'imagine' was very different from Mauro's, my or your modern thoughts… what else matters?
If Descartes had worked in English, all translations came from nearly 400 years ago.

You ask:

Did Descartes really say if you imagine it, it exists?

No, imagination is not sufficient for existence, but rather imagination in conjunction with direct experience, and that is different from conception. A quick example to clear up. You can imagine a circle, and you can imagine a square, but you cannot imagine a square circle. But you can conceive of it, otherwise we wouldn't be able to have this conversation about the square circle.
There's a technical distinction in philosophy of mind between the spontaneity of the senses and your ability to recreate that experience in the mind and conceivability, which is construed more broadly. From the Oxford Dictionary of Philosophy's article Conceivability:

Admissibility by the mind. Thinkability. If imagination entails the generation of mental imagery, then everything imaginable is conceivable, but not everything conceivable is imaginable. Something is conceivable if and only if it is possible to form a concept of it, but a concept need not involve an image

So, when Descartes says:

Further, the faculty of imagination which I possess, and of which I am conscious that I make use when I apply myself to the consideration of material things, is sufficient to persuade me of their existence: for, when I attentively consider what imagination is, I find that it is simply a certain application of the cognitive faculty... to a body which is immediately present to it, and which therefore exists.  And to render this quite clear, I remark, in the first place, the difference that subsists between imagination and pure intellection [or conception]. (emphases mind)

The body here is not the body of mind-body duality, that is, of the thinker with which the mind is associated, but the body that exists, what we would refer to as an object. Descartes is saying that when he's in the immediate presence of an object, and he applies his imagination to see it and visualize it, he can be relatively sure it exists. If you are in a room and you see an apple and you imagine what the apple feels like and tastes like, and are free to inspect the apple, it's existence is rather assured, but this is not the same as conception, in modern language 'conceivability'.
Conceivability in philosophy is a broader termed used to the ability to refer to something. One can refer to a unicorn, or a square circle, or a possible world, but the existence of these things are not assured in the way that our spontaneous presentation of the senses assures us. In this way, imagination has more the sense of picture or visualization, which is closer to the etymological root of imagination 'imago' (online-latin-dictionary.com which is the cognate of image. Conceivability is meant more broadly as in can be described in language. Thus, just because we can argue something exists, doesn't mean we can see it with our mind's eye.
This is a VERY important distinction, because even many professional philosophers seem to conflate what we can recreate with our senses in our mind and what we can describe with language. Many thinkers tacitly (and probably without awareness of the distinction) think because they can conceive of something, then it somehow exists. Modal realists and those who believe in the multiple-worlds interpretation of QM are two groups who believe that something exists despite no sensory or empirical evidence of its existence. Of course, many other philosophers push back on this. Once you get into the details, then you have to consider the meta-ontological theories of Plato, Aristotle, Meinong, Carnap, and Quine among others and things get technical.
(And to disclose my biases, conceivability is a WHOLLY insufficient basis for proof of existence, but then I lean heavy on science and the senses for proof of existence and meaningful discussion of the physical universe. You can conceive of infinity, for instance, but you certainly cannot imagine it, and therefore infinity is a measure of the potential rather than the actual, as another example.)

Descartes is in general as readable as he is brilliant, and this is part of his appeal. Yet when it comes to technical terms, some of his terms are strange for a contemporary reader and have different meanings from what we would expect from our linguistic habits. To take a first example, Descartes refers by the word objective to what we would now call subjective.
This applies also to Descartes's use of the word imagination. It does not mean exactly what we usually mean by this word. In our language imagination is usually contrasted with veridical sense perception. But in Descartes imagination is a broader term that includes veridical sense perception.
In the famous reflection on the wax in the Second Meditation, Descartes identities imagination with common sense:
“I prefer to pass on and consider whether I had a more evident and perfect conception of what the wax was when I first perceived it, and when I believed I knew it by means of the external senses or at least by the common sense as it is called, that is to say by the imaginative faculty.”
Again, the meaning of common sense in Descartes is not what we mean today by these words. His common sense is a psychic faculty, hypothesized by Aristotle, which synthesizes inputs from the familiar five senses. See more about it here.
So when Descartes refers to the imagination in the Sixth Meditation, as quoted in the OP, he actually means sense perception.
As to the trust that Descartes expresses there that the imagination (which here, at the beginning of the Sixth Meditation, actually means sense perception) presents to us really existing objects, this is clearly opposed to the skeptical approach that Descartes has been taking in the earlier Meditations. His change of approach is explained though throughout the Sixth Meditation. The central point is that Descartes has come to believe, by that stage in the Meditations, not only that God exists, but that God does not deceive us. And this Descartes interprets as meaning that if our faculties incline us to believe in something p, then we are justified to hold p to be true unless we have an available sign, some incoherence, which tells us that something is not quite right. In particular, we can usually trust our sense perception, to which he refers here by the word imagination, when it presents to us physical bodies, that these bodies really exist in front of us.

"if you imagine [something], then it exists."
No.  He is claiming that:
"If something imagines, then it exists."
This is intended to be paired with previous reasoning that posits "there exists something that imagines" by citing himself as an example.  However, you need not take Descartes as an example, you can take yourself as an example.  This is convenient to verify since you happen to be you.

so, if i understand correctly, if i am imagining a unicorn, the "body" referred to in the quote is MY body, not the unicorn.  Thank you!

NO. see text.

It seems incorrect and misleading to paraphrase Descartes as done in this answer. Bodies don't imagine anything. It's the mind that imagines things. The mind "clearly and distinctly" conceives that it exists. Imaginations always involve concrete, particular imagined objects -- which are not necessary for clear concepts -- D is also never claiming those imaginings exist just by being imagined or by being imaginable. The existence of any body (my body and other corporeal things) is based on sense perception and on the distinct and clear ideas that God exists and that God does not deceive me.

Hate to pile on, so I won't down vote, but the 'body' in the passage refers to an 'object' of a mind's attention as opposed to the body associated with the mind.

@JD no worries. It's been decades since I've read Descartes.  IMHO, the fact that wrong but plausible answers are wrong is also informative.  Downvote away.  :)
